# Content disappearing if I scroll and change tab simultaneously for web apps in IOS device, but it is working good in android devices and browser

Tags: css, ios

Content disappearing if I scroll and change tab simultaneously for web apps in IOS device but it is working in android and browser apps.

I tried with different solutions but nothing works.

Following are the properties which I will be trying to solve the problem.

`overflow: hidden -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; position: relative transform: translateZ(0);`

And I am expecting to have the content on UI, when I scroll and change the tab at once(simultaneously).